# fetching the data in postgres based on other preprocessing column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

In my database table(whitelist_domain_data) I have the fields id,url,data

The Url column has multiple urls like

```
http://www.dailystrength.org/c/Hidradenitis_Suppurativa/forum/8870995-solodyn-135-mg-works
http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090325215905AA6UVOa
http://navaspot.wordpress.com
```

I want to fetch the rows which have the same domain.

TABLE : Whitelist_domain_data

Schemas : id,url,data

```
select regexp_matches(url,'http\:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)\.org')  as domain,
       count(*) 
from whitelist_domain_data 
group by domain;
```

Should return:

```
dailystrength.org   200
```

**Ques**:
How to design the query to fetch all the urls data,if the url has the domain "dailystrength.org"?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error? Does it return the wrong results?

Comment: How to retrieve the data if the url has the domain "dailystrength.org"

Comment: What's wrong with `where url like 'http://dailystrength.org%'`

Comment: The URL may have "www.dailystrength.org" and answers.yahoo.com/dailystrength/... these combination we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with substring(), and you'll also probably want to use an expression index. Here's an example (I tweaked the regex to match what I think you want):

```
CREATE TABLE whitelist_domain_data(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  url TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX domain_index
  ON whitelist_domain_data (substring(url from 'https?\:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)'));

INSERT into whitelist_domain_data (url) VALUES
  ('http://www.dailystrength.org/c/Hidradenitis_Suppurativa/forum/8870995-solodyn-135-mg-works'),
  ('http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090325215905AA6UVOa'),
  ('http://navaspot.wordpress.com');

SELECT * FROM whitelist_domain_data WHERE substring(url from 'https?\:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)') = 'www.dailystrength.org';
```

Now this query can use the index. If this is something you plan on using a lot, you might consider also creating a specific function for it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_domain(text) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT substring($1 from 'https?\:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)');
$$;
```

Then the above becomes:

```
CREATE INDEX domain_index
  ON whitelist_domain_data (get_domain(url));

SELECT * FROM whitelist_domain_data WHERE get_domain(url) = 'www.dailystrength.org';
```

So then if you ever want to change what a domain is (to ignore subdomains, or whatever) you can just change the function and your queries will all still work. I think you'll have to reindex at that point, though.

I checked that this all works on Postgres 9.1, but it should be compatible with any recent version. Expression indexes and substring() both go back to the 7.x days.